# iAd crashes on 4.3 Simulator but works fine on 5.1

Tags: ios, iad, dealloc

I get this error on the 4.3 simulator just before crashing.  It works just fine on 5.1.  When I completely take out the iAd code it works fine on 4.3.  App was designed on 5.1 using arc.

```
[LinkViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I put a breakpoint on all exceptions.  I have ran it with NSZombie, NSDebug and NSMallocStackLogging all enabled.  How can I find what was deallocated?

Here's the thread:

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x0018e657 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x0018e522 in _CF_forwarding_prep_0 ()
#2  0x005ef0f0 in -[ADBannerView _sanitizeAndForwardErrorToDelegate:] ()
#3  0x0018dc7d in __invoking___ ()
#4  0x0018db51 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#5  0x0018ea04 in ___forwarding___ ()
#6  0x0018e522 in _CF_forwarding_prep_0 ()
#7  0x005f59f9 in -[ADDistributedMessagingCenter messagePort:receivedMessage:withData:] ()
#8  0x005f6012 in ADMessagePortCallBack ()
#9  0x001d4f4c in __CFMessagePortPerform ()
#10 0x001fe944 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#11 0x0015ecf7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#12 0x0015bf83 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x0015b840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x0015b761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x020331c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x02033289 in GSEventRun ()
#17 0x009bbc93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#18 0x00003125 in main at /Developer/Cecilia's Programs/Story/Story/main.m:17
#19 0x000029b5 in start ()
```

Here is my code:

```
- (void) createAdBannerView
{
    Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString (@"ADBannerView"); 
    if (classAdBannerView != nil)
    {
        self.adBannerView = [[classAdBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_adBannerView setRequiredContentSizeIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil]];
        [_adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
    }

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)     
    {
        [_adBannerView setFrame:CGRectOffset([_adBannerView frame], 0, -32)];
    }       

    else 
    {
        [_adBannerView setFrame:CGRectOffset([_adBannerView frame], 0, -66)];
    }

    [_adBannerView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:_adBannerView];  
}

- (void)fixupAdView
{
    if (_adBannerView != nil) 
    {        
        [_adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"fixupViews" context:nil];
        if (_adBannerViewIsVisible) 
        {
            CGRect adBannerViewFrame = [_adBannerView frame];
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.y = 20;
            [_adBannerView setFrame:adBannerViewFrame];
            CGRect iAdViewFrame = _iAdView.frame;

            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
            {
                iAdViewFrame.origin.y = 20;
                iAdViewFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - 32;
                _iAdView.frame = iAdViewFrame;
            }

            else
            {
                iAdViewFrame.origin.y = 20;
                iAdViewFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - 66;
                _iAdView.frame = iAdViewFrame;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            CGRect adBannerViewFrame = [_adBannerView frame];
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;

            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
            {
                adBannerViewFrame.origin.y = -52;
            }

            else
            {
                adBannerViewFrame.origin.y = -86;
            }

            [_adBannerView setFrame:adBannerViewFrame];
            CGRect iAdViewFrame = _iAdView.frame;
            iAdViewFrame.origin.y = 0;
            iAdViewFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
            _iAdView.frame = iAdViewFrame; 
            }

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner 
{   
    if (!_adBannerViewIsVisible)
    {                
        _adBannerViewIsVisible = YES;
        [self fixupAdView];
    }
 }

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{   
    if (_adBannerViewIsVisible)
    {       
         _adBannerViewIsVisible = NO;
        [self fixupAdView];
    }
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self fixupAdView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self createAdBannerView];
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: You can use *Instruments* to monitor the retain count of your object. Just run your project in "Profile" mode, this will launch Instruments. There you choose to watch for Zombies. When Instruments detects the zombie call, you just click on the "more information" arrow in the message - then enable the right column which will show you the call hiearchy which links directly to XCode.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Found it. Do you know what this means?
-[ADDistributedMessagingCenter messagePort:receivedMessage:withData:]